# Ionic serve --lab won't recognise href's

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working at a project in ionic and angular and I've encountered a program.
In the controller,I have a variable of this type:

```
$scope.var=["Visit this link: www.google.com" , "Visit this one too:www.facebook.com"];
```

In the view,I have

```
    < div ng-repeat="v in var">

    < p  ng-bind-html="v | linky"></p></div> ,
```

so that the links in the text do appear as links. The point is,what it's really made is a "href" link. My problem is that, when I run the project "ionic serve",it all works fine,but when I run in as "ionic serve --lab"(phone view),clicking on the links does nothing. 
Same happens with the other links too,but I managed to changed them from "href=source" to ng-click="function..." and deal with them in the controller,with window.open.

Will you please tell me what can I do here,as the link are automatically translated in href's which aren't recoginised by the phone mode test?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending your links with `http://` and changing binding to `<p ng-bind-html="v | linky: '_top'"></p>`.

( `'_parent'` also worked for me )

Comment: Nop,it's the same; it won't open in --lab mode.